# Why is the session always being destroyed af a few minutes in Yii framework 2.0?

Tags: php, session, yii2

I develop my web application with Yii framework 2.0. And I have two environments on the server, structured as follows.

```
/public_html
    /my-website
    /my-website-test
```

`my-website` is for the production and `my-website-test` is for the final testing. After I test that everything works fine on the `my-website-test` directory. I update my website by renaming `my-website` to `my-website-backup` and rename `my-website-test` to `my-website`. By doing this I can update my website very quickly without letting it go off for minutes. After that I still need `my-website-test` for further development. So I use the following command line to make an up-to-date copy.

```
cp -a my-website my-website-test
```

As result I have three following directories.

```
/public_html
    /my-website
    /my-website-backup
    /my-website-test
```

Now I am facing the problem that when I login on `www.my-website.com` and click around for a few minutes the session is always being destroyed with no reason. But when I login on `wwww.my-website-test.com` all the session works fine as it should be. I don't know where to start debugging while the session of the same source code/website (a copy) works fine on `www.my-website-test.com` but the session on `www.my-website.com` is always being destroyed. Does anyone have a clue where I should pay attention on for debugging?

Comment: Are you setting cookies? Are they unique for each environment? (I'm assuming your dev site has a different domain than prod?)

Comment: @Kisaragi for the login functionality I did not set any cookies, just session. It is provided by Yii 2.0 advanced template by default. My testing website has a different domain name e.g. www.my-website-test.com and my production website has a domain name e.g. www.my-website.com. But both of them are on the same server and in the same public_html directory.